# Getting the Bookmark of Every Pdf Page

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to get the bookmark information of a specific pdf page with "iTextSharp.text.pdf", I found how to get a collection of the bookmarks in a pdf, but I want to get it only for a specific page in a pdf, this is my code for the entire pdf:

```
public void ExportBookmarksToXml(string SourcePdfPath, string xmlOutputPath, string Password = "")
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SourcePdfPath, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(Password));
        IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(reader);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SimpleBookmark.ExportToXML(bookmarks, memoryStream, "ISO8859-1", true);
            //MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[0].Values.ToString());
            File.WriteAllBytes(xmlOutputPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

I need this, because I want to know for every bookmark how many pages and how many blank pages it has.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for get all bookmarks in every page of pdf.

```
IList<Dictionary<string, object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.GetBookmark(pdfReader);
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> bk in bookmarks)
{
string bjj = bk.Values.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```